# How to apply Ripple Effect Inner RecyclerView in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 RecyclerViews.

Z item belongs to Y. Y belongs to X.

Let's say there are A and B.

`A Item` layout looks like that.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcv_b_list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`B Item` layout looks like this.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcv_c_list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I touch `A Item`, It has ripple effect. However, `B Items` doesn't get the effect. So, only `non-B Items area` has the ripple effect. When I touch `B items area`, only one `B item` has the ripple effect.

I'd like to implement ripple effect as one which follows the parent view behaviour(A List). When I touch any part of `A item`, I hope it gets ripple effect include all the child views. Also, vice-versa, When I touch any items of `B list`, while that `A Item` have the ripple effect and also, it clicks only `A item`. Not `B item`.

Now, I have 3 RecyclerViews. X, Y, Z.
And I'd like to touch each Y item. And Z is not clickable.

How can I implement this feature?

Comment: To add ripple effect to parent, and wanna include all the children  then you need to apply the ripple drawable to setForeground of the View.

Comment: Please give me example answer. @MuhammedYalçınKuru

Comment: already foreground example given as answer. You should not intercept the parent touch by returning true in onTouch of child. So parent touch also being triggered. @c-an

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

to the parent view of your Item layout.

P.S: You may also set it to `:background` tag. Also you may use it with a android prefx like

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

You may apply whatever suits you or works for you.

Comment: When I click the inner RecyclerView, It doesn't select the parent item.